# Converting gmt to ist unparseable date exception

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
DateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
DateFormat indianFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
indianFormat .setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
String output = null;
try {
    Date timestamp = null;
    timestamp = utcFormat.parse(createdAt);
    output = indianFormat.format(timestamp);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    Log.d("ParseError", String.valueOf(e));
}
```

I want to convert GMT time of format "`2020-03-16T18:50:39.656Z`" to IST time of same format as GMT but I am getting unparseable exception

Comment: please add createdAt which you trying to convert

Comment: The `Z` is a constant value: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`

Comment: No, the `Z` indicates the time zone.  Don't put `' '` around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Z` at the end of your `createdAt` value is an ISO 8601 time zone symbol.  To parse it, you need to have `X` in your date format string, not `Z`.  Change your date format string to `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"` and your program will work.

Alternatively, you could keep `Z` in the date format string, but give your input as `"2020-03-16T18:50:39.656+0000"` - that is, use the four digit number to represent the time offset in the input, instead of `Z`.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Instant
.parse(
    "2020-03-16T18:50:39.656Z"
)
.atZone(
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" )
)
```

## *java.time*

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310.

## ISO 8601

Your input string is in standard ISO 8601 format. The `Z` on the end means UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds), and is pronounced “Zulu”.

The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

## `Instant`

Parse your input as a `Instant`, representing a moment as seen in UTC.

```
String input = "2020-03-16T18:50:39.656Z" ;
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

Adjust to India time.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Comment: what to use if min android level is 5.0

Comment: @ashishvyas See the "About java.time" section I added to the bottom of the Answer.